# Invert values from text list with equal sign in sublime text 2?

Tags: sublimetext2

I have a list in a text file with the countries around the world like this:

```
Afghanistan=AF, 
Åland Islands=AX, 
Albania=AL, 
Algeria=DZ, 
American Samoa=AS, 
AndorrA=AD, 
Angola=AO, 
Anguilla=AI, 
Antarctica=AQ, 
Antigua and Barbuda=AG, 
Argentina=AR, 
Armenia=AM, 
Aruba=AW, 
Australia=AU, 
Austria=AT, 
Azerbaijan=AZ, 
Bahamas=BS, 
...
```

Can be possible to invert the sides of the equal sign with sublime text 2?
The command should do something like this:

`{value}={text}` should be converted to `{text}={value}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **Replace** function with [Regular Expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) on Sublime Text like this:

Find-->Replace

It will open a panel on the bottom where you can insert what you want to find and the text to replace with.
Enable regular expressions by pressing the  `.*` button on the left.

For your case, on the Find what:   `(.*)=(.*),`  and on the Replace With:  `$2=$1,`  i think is sufficent.

This regex will swap the words.